# How does Method present in List interface implemented without creating Objects in arraylist or LinkedList in Below Selenium Concept

Tags: java, list, selenium-webdriver, arraylist, linked-list

List < WebElement> LElement=driver.findElements(By.tagname("a"));

In the above case the driver.findElements will return the list of WebElement and Now we have the Object of List that is "LElement" ,Now suppose if i want to get the first Element i can use below code
LElement.get(0);

But my doubt here is the get() method is present in List interface So i should Create Object of Either ArrayList or LinkedList to implement this method..But in above case i can directly get result of get method without implementing from ArrayList or Linked List and directly from interface..Can somebody explain me about this?

Answer (score 0):

This question is irrespective of selenium and is a concept called polymorphism in OOP.

The `List` interface provides abstract methods and the class implementing `List` should provide an implementation body for the abstract methods. Therefore the method `get()` in the `List` interface is implemented in the class `ArrayList` and the other implementations of the `List` interface. `ArrayList` is a type of `List`, therefore we can have something like this:

```
List<WebElement> webElements = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now let's say I want to create the API `findElements` for Selenium. If I create the method like this:

```
public ArrayList<WebElement> findElements(input..){
```

It would be tightly coupled with ArrayList and everyone will have to use ArrayList from their end to use that API's method, which is not desirable.

A better solution would be to use some abstract concept to represent the `ArrayList`, which turns out to be the `List` interface.

```
public List<WebElement> findElements(input..){
     List<WebElements> webElements = new ArrayList<>();

     webElements.addAll(some operations to populate the list)

     return webElements;
}
```

This one is more flexible, how? Let's say after releasing the app, we deducted the implementation of ArrayList is not the best option for us to use for that use case, and we would like to use to LinkedList instead. Using the first way of writing the API, the consumers of the API would have to make the change from their side as well. Using the better way, they do not need to do anything :)

The List is still an instance of ArrayList; in the provided example. Selenium must have implemented something similar. We are getting a concrete implementation of List when we are invoking `findElements`, it is just that we do not know what implementation class we are getting but we do know that it provides implementation bodies for the abstract methods found in the List interface and we can use them.